# Firebase - Query Indexed Data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, indexing

I have the following Firebase data for markers on a google map:

[image]

'g' is the Geohash of the lat('y') long('x') data.

The rules have the following:

```
    "markers": {
      // Schema validation
      "$key": {
        //Create Index on geohash
        ".indexOn":"g",
        // Key validation
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['y', 'x'])",
        // Location coordinates validation
        "y" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -90 && newData.val() <= 90"
        },
        "x" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -180 && newData.val() <= 180"
        }
      },
    },
```

I want to find all the markers in the database that have the Geohash "dpt".

I have tried the following, but this doesn't work as 'key' is not a wildcard for the Children of "markers".
How do I form the query to check "g" of each of the Children of "markers" and then save the parent push key that identifies the marker(s) that match the Query.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('markers').child('key');
ref.orderByChild('g').startAt('9tb').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var geoHash = snapshot.val();
  console.log("Geohash: ", geoHash);
});
```

Here is the textual JSON sample Firebase data:

```
{
  "markers" : {
    "-KlRW2_rba1zBrDPpxSl" : {
      "g" : "9ru",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -117.826127,
      "y" : 44.781139
    },
    "-KlTqMQyCcp14K_aMo9g" : {
      "g" : "9ru",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -117.81246,
      "y" : 44.782722
    },
    "-Kldr6aLW-S2oGUdjAzI" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.028278,
      "y" : 48.041726
    },
    "-Kldw5z-D_cdrKnWCmp_" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.059073,
      "y" : 48.06427
    },
    "-Kle3Cx0QeqRy1h7aATN" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.146601,
      "y" : 48.084727
    },
    "-Kle7Fv1xkfb-7tr1P2L" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.183749,
      "y" : 48.095725
    },
    "-Kle7jffOcDuUzjAZg5F" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.18631,
      "y" : 48.096281
    },
    "-KleA4K1dojl1WtcWPSV" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.213735,
      "y" : 48.097471
    },
    "-KleABUDV4jcGpa8r6Ve" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.213725,
      "y" : 48.097485
    },
    "-KleKH81yer28MoVfEMW" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.325905,
      "y" : 48.106662
    },
    "-KleUD0juBdYZeoe_z-q" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.429659,
      "y" : 48.119794
    },
    "-Klo34L_G5agEOqpbovd" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.396003,
      "y" : 48.571614
    },
    "-Klo3R9kl7BA75jLv7Xh" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.396094,
      "y" : 48.571911
    },
    "-KltPx4gNnU0FW9BbRQL" : {
      "g" : "c0x",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.961927,
      "y" : 49.149734
    },
    "-KltQHHSeS46eRZiEqJ5" : {
      "g" : "c0x",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.962496,
      "y" : 49.149894
    },
    "-KltZAKh747Wp276lwtv" : {
      "g" : "c0x",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -124.002884,
      "y" : 49.187565
    },
    "-KlyGT1ti-2h3Gvj9JTA" : {
      "g" : "c0z",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -124.446747,
      "y" : 49.354767
    },
    "-KlyyQ707QUZgJo4raj0" : {
      "g" : "c0z",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -124.868005,
      "y" : 49.548976
    },
    "-Klyz0xV1HM4CC1cRkc2" : {
      "g" : "c0z",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -124.868662,
      "y" : 49.550011
    },
    "-KmDS0eTTxvcTRyDo6Ey" : {
      "g" : "c0z",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.753916,
      "y" : 49.470945
    },
    "-KmJ5fZU7FGepOM-Dsd3" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.640735,
      "y" : 48.865098
    },
    "-KmTUx_PdegkTMa-U0_Q" : {
      "g" : "c28",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -123.148974,
      "y" : 48.515291
    },
    "-KoNxTtS9tmuIi5WqSJ0" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.961665,
      "y" : 33.487971
    },
    "-KomZRSjPvEY32NccKjP" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.938777,
      "y" : 33.372255
    },
    "-KomZicmIkAugvZoYOFk" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.93924,
      "y" : 33.372432
    },
    "-Kom_Hkh69ay27Vcvd8g" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.937975,
      "y" : 33.372203
    },
    "-Kom__PTIp5XegcmBfg-" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.937818,
      "y" : 33.372542
    },
    "-Kom_x70rXZSp52uAO77" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.937855,
      "y" : 33.373511
    },
    "-KomaAzSPC3GBSgHxauG" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.938118,
      "y" : 33.373924
    },
    "-KomaRXxHhL6WhPlEYoY" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.938446,
      "y" : 33.374228
    },
    "-Komazt-91BrlsyXRBTa" : {
      "g" : "9tb",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.937611,
      "y" : 33.372948
    },
    "-Koo6156pLEDnSX6W2is" : {
      "g" : "9xh",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -105.768036,
      "y" : 39.773127
    },
    "-Koo6HaacQSYL9WUFHFk" : {
      "g" : "9xh",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -105.608521,
      "y" : 39.683015
    },
    "-KosfSpl7Jnv0y2Yayue" : {
      "g" : "9xh",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -106.109965,
      "y" : 40.074011
    },
    "-Kp6Wq6tc54oUKcIoVPY" : {
      "g" : "9w0",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.503542,
      "y" : 35.064289
    },
    "-Kp6X0s4WpIGGxU31nDQ" : {
      "g" : "9w0",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.584362,
      "y" : 35.111022
    },
    "-KpBpkjX2tYoaGbQIkVV" : {
      "g" : "9w0",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.852989,
      "y" : 34.564051
    },
    "-KpBqBS10FM5LFT96yed" : {
      "g" : "9w0",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.852024,
      "y" : 34.564459
    },
    "-KpBrZyra82zHA6jksmE" : {
      "g" : "9w0",
      "v" : true,
      "x" : -111.850959,
      "y" : 34.549598
    }
  }
}
```

Rules:

```
    "markers": {
      //Create Index on geohash
      ".indexOn":"g",
      // Schema validation
      "$key": {
        // Key validation
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['y', 'x'])",
        // Location coordinates validation
        "y" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -90 && newData.val() <= 90"
        },
        "x" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -180 && newData.val() <= 180"
        }
      },
    },
```

and here is the node.js code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var config = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: ''
});
console.log('reading test database Geohash Data function');
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('markers');
ref.orderByChild('g').startAt('9tb').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var geoHash = snapshot.val();
  console.log("Geohash: ", geoHash);
});
```

This is the output:

```
reading test database Geohash Data function
Geohash:  {
  '-Kldr6aLW-S2oGUdjAzI': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.028278, y: 48.041726 },
  '-Kldw5z-D_cdrKnWCmp_': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.059073, y: 48.06427 },
  '-Kle3Cx0QeqRy1h7aATN': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.146601, y: 48.084727 },
  '-Kle7Fv1xkfb-7tr1P2L': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.183749, y: 48.095725 },
  '-Kle7jffOcDuUzjAZg5F': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.18631, y: 48.096281 },
  '-KleA4K1dojl1WtcWPSV': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.213735, y: 48.097471 },
  '-KleABUDV4jcGpa8r6Ve': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.213725, y: 48.097485 },
  '-KleKH81yer28MoVfEMW': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.325905, y: 48.106662 },
  '-KleUD0juBdYZeoe_z-q': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.429659, y: 48.119794 },
  '-Klo34L_G5agEOqpbovd': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.396003, y: 48.571614 },
  '-Klo3R9kl7BA75jLv7Xh': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.396094, y: 48.571911 },
  '-KltPx4gNnU0FW9BbRQL': { g: 'c0x', v: true, x: -123.961927, y: 49.149734 },
  '-KltQHHSeS46eRZiEqJ5': { g: 'c0x', v: true, x: -123.962496, y: 49.149894 },
  '-KltZAKh747Wp276lwtv': { g: 'c0x', v: true, x: -124.002884, y: 49.187565 },
  '-KlyGT1ti-2h3Gvj9JTA': { g: 'c0z', v: true, x: -124.446747, y: 49.354767 },
  '-KlyyQ707QUZgJo4raj0': { g: 'c0z', v: true, x: -124.868005, y: 49.548976 },
  '-Klyz0xV1HM4CC1cRkc2': { g: 'c0z', v: true, x: -124.868662, y: 49.550011 },
  '-KmDS0eTTxvcTRyDo6Ey': { g: 'c0z', v: true, x: -123.753916, y: 49.470945 },
  '-KmJ5fZU7FGepOM-Dsd3': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.640735, y: 48.865098 },
  '-KmTUx_PdegkTMa-U0_Q': { g: 'c28', v: true, x: -123.148974, y: 48.515291 },
  '-KoNxTtS9tmuIi5WqSJ0': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.961665, y: 33.487971 },
  '-KomZRSjPvEY32NccKjP': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.938777, y: 33.372255 },
  '-KomZicmIkAugvZoYOFk': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.93924, y: 33.372432 },
  '-Kom_Hkh69ay27Vcvd8g': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.937975, y: 33.372203 },
  '-Kom__PTIp5XegcmBfg-': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.937818, y: 33.372542 },
  '-Kom_x70rXZSp52uAO77': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.937855, y: 33.373511 },
  '-KomaAzSPC3GBSgHxauG': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.938118, y: 33.373924 },
  '-KomaRXxHhL6WhPlEYoY': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.938446, y: 33.374228 },
  '-Komazt-91BrlsyXRBTa': { g: '9tb', v: true, x: -111.937611, y: 33.372948 },
  '-Koo6156pLEDnSX6W2is': { g: '9xh', v: true, x: -105.768036, y: 39.773127 },
  '-Koo6HaacQSYL9WUFHFk': { g: '9xh', v: true, x: -105.608521, y: 39.683015 },
  '-KosfSpl7Jnv0y2Yayue': { g: '9xh', v: true, x: -106.109965, y: 40.074011 },
  '-Kp6Wq6tc54oUKcIoVPY': { g: '9w0', v: true, x: -111.503542, y: 35.064289 },
  '-Kp6X0s4WpIGGxU31nDQ': { g: '9w0', v: true, x: -111.584362, y: 35.111022 },
  '-KpBpkjX2tYoaGbQIkVV': { g: '9w0', v: true, x: -111.852989, y: 34.564051 },
  '-KpBqBS10FM5LFT96yed': { g: '9w0', v: true, x: -111.852024, y: 34.564459 },
  '-KpBrZyra82zHA6jksmE': { g: '9w0', v: true, x: -111.850959, y: 34.549598 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.child('key')` in your code is not needed. So:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('markers');
ref.orderByChild('g').startAt('9tb').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

---

Indexes need to be defined on the level where you execute the query, so for you that is:

```
"markers": {
  ".indexOn":"g",
  ...
},
```

---

The third (and hopefully final problem) is that you're not displaying the results in order. When you call `snapshot.val()` you get back a JSON object, and the keys in a JSON object are by definition not ordered, so you end up logging them in whatever order your client decides.

If you use Firebase's built-in `forEach` method to loop over the results, they will be printed in order:

```
ref.orderByChild('g').startAt('9tb').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.val());
  });
});
```

Working code: https://jsbin.com/qacefog/2/edit?js,console

And with that, you can see that it starts with the `9tb` hashes, and then moves on to the ones **after** that, which is what `startAt` is supposed to do. If you *only* want the geohashes that start **with** `9tb`, you need to include and `endAt` clause, like this:

```
ref.orderByChild('g').startAt('9tb').endAt('9tb~')...
```

This is precisely what the GeoFire libraries do.

Comment: Thanks, Frank.  I get all of the markers with a Geohash of 'dpt' if I start and end at 'dpt', however, if I only start at 'dpt' and print the results to the console the first marker has a Geohash of 'c28'.  I had expected the query to return all markers with a Geohash of 'dpt' followed by 'dpu', etc.  Is this correct?

Comment: That seems unexpected indeed. Can you set up a reproduction in a site like jsbin, or stackblitz, so I can have a look?

Comment: Sure.  Is there a public Firebase project where I can upload some sample data for the JavaScript to access? Or, I can send you the JSON data along with the code.  I'm actually using a node.js script to test.

Comment: I have a separate project (on the free plan) for this purpose that I've been using for many years. If you share the data as textual JSON, I'd have already added it there to test. I recommend you either create such a project yourself too, or add the data as text and I can add it to my `stackoverflow` project. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I added the data, node.js code and rules above.  Searched for '9tb' in this example, but same results - get 'c28' first. If I start and end at '9tb' it returns only markers with '9tb' Geohash.

Comment: BTW, I tried GeoFire for about 18 months ago and it failed when zooming out with a large radius.  I posted the issue on Github (https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/129) but it was never addressed.  Our app has markers all over the world and we need to update the map as the user zooms in and out even if that includes the entire world. Also would want to add clustering if GeoFire was updated.